# Android - Why I can't use NoActionBar in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme

I'm trying to hide Actionbar and use Toolbar instead, But if I change ***Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar*** It does hide but application crash at line  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

although it does hide using this ***getSupportActionBar().hide();*** but then I can't use this code

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

because application crash at setSupportActionBar(toolbar):

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.unchallenged.news;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.unchallenged.news.MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.unchallenged.news">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 26*

If i use NoActionbar in style ***Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar*** then my application crash and catlog are:

```
07-13 13:26:53.781 18978-18978/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.unchallenged.news, PID: 18978
                                                   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field title of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.example.unchallenged.news-2/base.apk)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:482)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:325)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                       at com.example.unchallenged.news.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3208)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
07-13 13:26:53.781 18978-18978/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18978 SIG: 9
```

**Build.grade(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.unchallenged.news"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: I think by updating SDK it will solve your error.

Comment: where is you code ? the xml file doesn't contain the toolbar

Comment: @RounakLahoti Android Studio is already on latest version

Comment: @OussemaAroua doesn't matter that My problem is if I do use NoActionBar application crashed at setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: are using other modules ?

Comment: Did you check your SDK manager to see if any updates to your "SDK" is available?

Comment: Or try disabling instant run.

Comment: @OussemaAroua No bro,

Comment: @MohammedJunaid everything is up to date. and yes I tried disabling Instant run

Comment: did you clean & rebuild your project?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid yes I've tried this Still application crashing if I use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: did you add <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> in your styles.xml?

Comment: Yes bro I also tried this tried this.

Comment: then maybe you should try going back to 25.3.1 version library instaed of 26.0.0 - alpha1 since it is in alpha there maybe a chance of internal library issue.

Comment: You were right.. I've change back to 25.3.1 and SDKversion and compile version to 25 it's working now :D make it answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Mohammed Junaid said.. I was using  "26.0.0 - alpha1" library version so it may have a some issue , So change back to "25.3.1" and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `activity_main.xml` should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.unchallenged.news.MainActivity">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

Edit your `style.xml`

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Still application crashed at setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); because i'm using NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Edit your MainActivity:

```
package com.example.unchallenged.news;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

And activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.unchallenged.news.MainActivity">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

If error still occurs, check the support library version in your gradle.build file. It can be like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Edit your post and provide current version, after that we can try another approach.

Comment: I've tried above code application crashed at line setSupportActionBar(toolbar); Also I have updated my question